# Storing a variable size JSON array in an iOS element

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

```
{
  "bidstatus":[
        {"bidstatusid":"1","bidstatus":"Quoted"},
        {"bidstatusid":"2","bidstatus":"Closed"},
        {"bidstatusid":"3","bidstatus":"Awarded"}
        ],
  "config":{
        "adminfee":"100",
        "percentcommission":"10",
        "premiumfee":"0"
        },
  "lvlsubj":{
        "Primary 1":["English","Geography","Maths","Science"],
        "Primary 2":["English","Geography","History"],
        "Primary 3":["Maths","Science"]
        }
}
```

I have an incoming JSON reply from an API which returns the above.  Existing iOS code uses AFNetworking to parse the JSON.  I'm able to store bidstatus as NSArray and config as NSDictionary.  However, I can't get lvlsubj to be stored properly.  This object looks like a 2D array with the second level array of variable size.

How do I go about it?

The existing code is pretty straightforward.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSString* strRequestLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", SERVICEPATH, @"get_var.php"];
[manager GET: strRequestLink
  parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
         [GlobalPool sharedObject].m_dictPaymentConfig = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"config"] mutableCopy];
         [GlobalPool sharedObject].m_arrayBidStatus = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"bidstatus"] mutableCopy];
         //[GlobalPool sharedObject].m_arrayLevelSubject = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"lvlsubj"] mutableCopy];

     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

         [self showServerConnectionError];
     }];
```

Comment: lvlsubj is a dictionary with primary 1 as first key which is an  array. same as you did with bid status do it with primary 1 and so on,after retrieving from lvlsubj.

Comment: Looks like `lvlsubj` is a `NSDictionary` of `NSArrays`. So calling `[lvlsubj objectForKey""]` will return an array. Sorry, on my phone or would comment as an answer but not able to properly test.

Comment: Thanks both, will try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions above, I managed to get them stored and read.

Store it as NSDictionary.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSString* strRequestLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", SERVICEPATH, @"get_var.php"];
[manager GET: strRequestLink
  parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
         [GlobalPool sharedObject].m_dictPaymentConfig = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"config"] mutableCopy];
         [GlobalPool sharedObject].m_arrayBidStatus = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"bidstatus"] mutableCopy];
         [GlobalPool sharedObject].m_dictLevelSubject = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"lvlsubj"] mutableCopy];

     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

         [self showServerConnectionError];
     }];
```

Then use allKeys to store keys in NSArray. Using the keys, read from NSDictionary (which will return array).

The code here populates a picker with the keys.  Upon selecting a value, it will read from the NSDictionary to get the corresponding object (NSArray) and populate a second picker.

```
- (IBAction)actionChooseLevel:(id)sender {
    NSArray* arrayKeys = [[GlobalPool sharedObject].m_dictLevelSubject allKeys];
    if (arrayKeys.count == 0)
        return;

    [arrayPickerItems removeAllObjects];
    for (int nIdx = 0; nIdx < arrayKeys.count; nIdx++)
    {
        NSMutableString* strInfo = [arrayKeys objectAtIndex:nIdx];
        [arrayPickerItems addObject:strInfo];
    }

    [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Choose Level" rows:arrayPickerItems initialSelection:nSelectedLevelIdx > 0 ? nSelectedLevelIdx : 0 target:self successAction:@selector(itemWasSelected:element:) cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:sender];
}

- (IBAction)actionChooseSubject:(id)sender {
    NSArray* arrayObject = [[GlobalPool sharedObject].m_dictLevelSubject objectForKey:self.m_lblSelectedLevel.text];
    if (arrayObject.count == 0)
        return;

    [arrayPickerItems removeAllObjects];
    for (int nIdx = 0; nIdx < arrayObject.count; nIdx++)
    {
        NSMutableString* strInfo = [arrayObject objectAtIndex:nIdx];
        [arrayPickerItems addObject:strInfo];
    }

    [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Choose Subject" rows:arrayPickerItems initialSelection:nSelectedSubjectIdx > 0 ? nSelectedSubjectIdx : 0 target:self successAction:@selector(itemWasSelected:element:) cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:sender];
}
```